# The conservation of energy in both the cases: Will it be different or the same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

On an inclined plane of same height $h$ and every factor the same but the only factor changes is the presence of friction. In the first case the friction is present in the top half and in the second case the friction is present in the second half of the inclined plane...
Which one has more kinetic energy when the ball reaches the end of the incline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy lost to friction will be $F_k d$ where $F_k$ is the magnitude of the kinetic friction force and $d$ is the distance over which the friction acts.

From the description the $d$ is equal in both cases. So which one is greater depends only on the force.

In the usual case $F_k=\mu_k N$ where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction and $N$ is the magnitude of the normal force. Since the normal force is the same in both cases and since the coefficient is also the same in both cases then the force is the same in both cases. So then the energy lost to friction is the same and the KE is the same in both cases.

Note: $F_k=\mu_k N$ is a very simplistic formula that approximates real friction. In reality friction can be a function of velocity too, and temperature, and other factors. So if those other factors are important then $F_k$ may not be equal in the two cases, like the simplified model suggests